# undefined reference to 'nCr'

Tags: c, linux, reference, linker, undefined

I'm trying to compile my program to run on linux but it doesn't work because of this error.

I compile with gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -m64 -o formula formula.c nCr.s and the error i get is:

```
/tmp/ccnNz7Jr.o: In function `main':
formula.c:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `nCr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Here's the code from the file formula.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "nCr.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int x = 0;
int y;
int z;

struct timeval start, end;

if (argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'h') {
    printf("Usage: formula <positive integer>");
} else {
    y = atoi(argv[1]);

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    printf("(1 + x)^%i = 1+", y);

    if (y == 0)
        printf("0");


    if (y > 12) {
        printf("%s\n","Please enter a number 12 or below. Anything higher results in overflow, the answer you want is not the answer you will get.");
    }

    for (; x <= y; x++) {

        z = nCr(y, x);

        if (z == -1) {
            printf("Multiplication overflow. \n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (x != 0)
                printf("%i x^%i ",z , x);

            if (x != y && x != 0)
                printf("+ ");
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

}

printf("\n%ld microseconds\n", ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec)
      - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)));

return 0;
}
```

ncr.h

```
#ifndef _NCR_H_
#define _NCR_H_

extern int Factorial(int n);

extern int nCr(int n, int r);

#endif /* _NCR_H_ */
```

and there's an assembly file called nCr.s

```
    .globl _factorial
    _factorial:
    Leh_func_begin2:
    pushq   %rbp
    Ltmp3:
movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
movl    $1, -20(%rbp)
jmp LBB2_2
LBB2_1:
movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
movl    -20(%rbp), %ecx
imull   %ecx, %eax
movl    %eax, -16(%rbp)
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
addl    $1, %eax
movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)
LBB2_2:
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
cmpl    %ecx, %eax
jle LBB2_1
movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
popq    %rbp
ret

.globl _nCr
_nCr:
Leh_func_begin1:
pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
subq    $32, %rsp
Ltmp2:
movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
xorb    %cl, %cl
movl    %eax, %edi
movb    %cl, %al
callq   _factorial
movl    %eax, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -20(%rbp)
movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
subl    %edx, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -24(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx
xorb    %dl, %dl
movl    %ecx, %edi
movb    %dl, %al
callq   _factorial
movl    %eax, %ecx
movl    -24(%rbp), %edx
xorb    %sil, %sil
movl    %edx, %edi
movb    %sil, %al
movl    %ecx, -32(%rbp)
callq   _factorial
movl    %eax, %ecx
movl    -32(%rbp), %esi
imull   %ecx, %esi
movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
movl    -20(%rbp), %ecx
movl    -28(%rbp), %esi
movl    %ecx, %eax
cltd
idivl   %esi
movl    %eax, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -16(%rbp)
movl    %ecx, -12(%rbp)
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
addq    $32, %rsp
popq    %rbp
ret
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, can't seem to figure out why it's not compiling. It compiles just fine on mac but I need to get it run on linux.

Comment: change `extern int Factorial...` to `extern int _factorial...` and change `extern int nCr...` to `extern int _nCr...` in `ncr.h`. You are telling gcc that it will find the definitions of `Factorial` and `nCr` in some other file, but your .s defines them as `_factorial` and `_nCr`. Or you can change the names on your asm file and avoid changes in function calls.

Comment: THANK YOU! That finally fixed it, been pulling my hair out over this for the last 2 hours. Extremely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is not able to find `extern int Factorial(int n);` and `extern int nCr(int n, int r);` definitions because they are called `_factorial:` and `_nCr:` in your asm file. Change those labels to match the decl and your code will compile.

I noticed that you have only one call of `nCr` in the main function, so I think it is better to change decls in your .h. So your `nCr.h` will be:

```
#ifndef _NCR_H_
#define _NCR_H_

extern int _factorial(int n);

extern int _nCr(int n, int r);

#endif /* _NCR_H_ */
```

And you have to call `_nCr(...)` at main.